# Result of "Java utility" is not matching with the "C# utility" while signing data

Tags: java, c#, digital-signature

Well, I'm stuck in process of signing the data using Java utility.

I've one requirement to create the Java program which will sign the data based on the base64 encoded string provided as an input data.

Here, I'm able to generate the signed data using the specific certificate provided, but the problem is: the result of "Java utility" is not matching with the "C# utility" while signing data.

**Here is my C# program:**

```
//Get certificate based on given thumbprint
X509Certificate2 certificate = GetCertificate(certThumbPrint);
ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(Convert.FromBase64String(data));
SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, false);
CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(certificate);
signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, false);

return Convert.ToBase64String(signedCms.Encode());
```

Where `data` would be the base64 encoded string, and `certThumbPrint` would be the unique value of the specific certificate.

**Here is my Java Program:**

```
package com.test;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import sun.security.pkcs.ContentInfo;
import sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7;
import sun.security.pkcs.SignerInfo;
import sun.security.util.DerOutputStream
import sun.security.util.DerValue;
import sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId;
import sun.security.x509.X500Name;

public class TestSignData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //First load the keystore object by providing the p12 file path
        KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
        //replace testPass with the p12 password/pin
        clientStore.load(null, null);

        Enumeration<String> aliases = clientStore.aliases();
        String aliaz = "";
        System.out.println(aliases.hasMoreElements());
        while(aliases.hasMoreElements()){
            aliaz = aliases.nextElement();
            System.out.println("aliaz::"+aliaz);
            if(clientStore.isKeyEntry(aliaz)){
                break;
            }
        }
        X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate)clientStore.getCertificate(aliaz);

        //Data to sign
        byte[] dataToSign = "QXNob2s=".getBytes();
        int nread = dataToSign.length;

        //compute signature:
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("Sha1WithRSA");
        signature.initSign((PrivateKey)clientStore.getKey(aliaz, null));
        signature.update(dataToSign, 0, nread);
        byte[] signedData = signature.sign();

        //load X500Name
        X500Name xName =  new X500Name(c.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
        System.out.println("xName:::"+xName);

        //load serial number
        BigInteger serial   = c.getSerialNumber();
        //laod digest algorithm
        AlgorithmId digestAlgorithmId = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.SHA_oid);
        //load signing algorithm
        AlgorithmId signAlgorithmId = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.RSAEncryption_oid);

        //Create SignerInfo:
        SignerInfo sInfo = new SignerInfo(xName, serial, digestAlgorithmId, signAlgorithmId, signedData);
        //Create ContentInfo:
        ContentInfo cInfo = new ContentInfo(ContentInfo.DIGESTED_DATA_OID, new DerValue(DerValue.tag_OctetString, dataToSign));
        //Create PKCS7 Signed data
        PKCS7 p7 = new PKCS7(new AlgorithmId[] { digestAlgorithmId }, cInfo,
                new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] { c },
                new SignerInfo[] { sInfo });
        //Write PKCS7 to bYteArray
        DerOutputStream dOut = new DerOutputStream();
        p7.encodeSignedData(dOut);
        byte[] encodedPKCS7 = dOut.toByteArray();

        String base64SignatureData = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(encodedPKCS7);
        System.out.println(base64SignatureData);

    }
}
```

Can anyone please guide me on this to get the exact result which "C#" based utility returns?

**Note:** While checking this program in your local, you can take any certificate as an input, but result of the both programs should be same, which is the primary requirement for me.

I would really appreciate if anyone can give me the quick response on this.

Thank you!

Comment: *"Can anyone please guide me on this to get the exact result which "C#" based utility returns?"* - Why? The padding is probably randomized, so you will always get different results if you sign it repeatedly and everything stays the same. You should try to sign in one language and verify in the other to check the compatibility. Then you should check the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

First, as Artjom commented, digital signature is not always deterministic and it is quite possible for two (or more) signatures of the same data with the same key to be different and both (or all) valid. You do not verify a signature by comparing it to a newly-generated or even pre-existing signature.

You are doing several things which are definitely or probably wrong and need to be fixed, and other things which might be different but not necessarily wrong.

Definite: your dotNET code is using the data after decoding from base64, your Java code is using the encoded value (both to hash and to send).

Semi-Definite: you are using the certificate subject and serial in creating SignerInfo, it should be issuer and serial. If your cert is self-signed, issuer and subject are the same and this doesn't matter.

Definite: you are using (the OID for) digested-data as the contentType for the data, it should be data . (digested-data is the type for a message of structure DigestedData which contains *both* the data and the digest(s) i.e. [section 7 of rfc3369](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3369#section-7) )

Likely: MSDN doesn't say that I can find (and I can't easily test) what hash dotNET uses for RSA signing, but SHA1 is no longer considered best practice so it might well use something better. If so this is a difference that is not definitely wrong even though poor practice.

Likely: Similarly I don't know if dotNET uses SignedAttributes, but I'd expect it's likely since it's good practice. Your Java code definitely doesn't. If so this is a difference, but not really wrong.

Likely: Similarly I don't know if dotNET automatically includes/adds chain certificates, which is explicitly recommended and good practice. Your Java code doesn't. If your cert is self-signed there are no chain certs and this doesn't matter.

PS: java 8 officially has `java.util.Base64` and back to 6 (at least) since you're apparently happy with unsupported classes `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64` means you don't need commons.